# UIWebView zoom on load?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am loading content into a UIWebView via a string :

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *html = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:(@"<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body { text-overflow: ellipsis; font-size: 14px;width: 300px;font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial;}table {text-overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word font-size: 14px;width: 300px;}tr {padding: 5px;}h1 {font-size: 16px;}h2 {font-size: 14px;color: #aa1121;}h3 {font-size: 14px;}th {color: #aa1121;}li {text-overflow: ellipsis;}</style></head><body><h1>%@</h1><p>%@ - %@</p>%@</body></html>"), selectedTitle, selectedpubDate, selectedmodDate, selectedContent] autorelease]; 

    NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = 10.5;"];
    [wvContent stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
    [wvContent loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil]; 

    self.navigationItem.title = selectedTitle;
}
```

This all works fine, loading the data in correctly, however, if i want to zoom in and out and turn the 'Scaling - Scale pages to fit' on it zoom my text out, making me double click to get it back to full screen.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
wvContent.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron but I have this already set via interface builder.